# Jquery Filter Out Radio Buttons ( .not( ) )

Tags: php, jquery, filter

I want to remove the radiobuttons from my multiple choice quiz so users can review their answers.  I put all of the questions to be reviewed in a div called `reviewQuestions`

```
var question = '#question' + zz; // zz is a variable that produces a number
var someVariable = $(question).not("input[type=radio]").html();  //this is the line that doesn't work
                    $('#reviewQuestions').append(someVariable);
```

php that generates the quiz:

```
echo "<div id='question" . $question_number . "' class='quest'>";
echo "<div class='questionItself'>" . $qn . ". " . $question . "</div>";
echo "<div class='answerContainer'>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='qr".$question_number."' value='a'> A. " . $chA . "<br><br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='qr".$question_number."' value='b'> B. " . $chB . "<br><br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='qr".$question_number."' value='c'> C. " . $chC . "<br><br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='qr".$question_number."' value='d'> D. " . $chD . "<br><br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='qr".$question_number."' value='e'> E. " . $chE . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to grab *direct/nested* children

```
var someVariable = $(question).find('*').not("input[type=radio]").html();
```